# Upload a file to FTP using PHP without the file being damaged

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to upload a file to my ftp server using php.

If I use this, the file load works but the file is damaged. I am a beginner in php, I hope to solve this problem soon, I appreciate any minimal help, thanks for your attention.

**This is the form I use to load the file, it's a simple html.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $ftp_server = "yourHosting.com";

        $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("error $ftp_server"); 

        $file = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];

        if (ftp_login($conn_id, 'userHere', 'passwordHere')) {
            echo "<br>Session started.";
            ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
            ftp_put($conn_id, '../myhosting.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/'.$file, $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], FTP_ASCII) or die("Image not uploaded");
        } else {
            echo "<br>Session not started.";
        }

        ftp_close($conn_id);
    }
?>
```

If I change the name tmp_name to name that the file does not load, I don't know what I will do wrong.

```
ftp_put($conn_id, '../myhosting.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/'.$file, $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], FTP_ASCII) or die("Image not uploaded");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `FTP_ASCII` to `FTP_BINARY`.

Explanation:

`FTP_ASCII` for plain-text files.
`FTP_BINARY` for any file type, including plain-text files. E.g. a JPEG file is binary in nature.

Behind the scenes, with `FTP_ASCII` any encounter of the null character (ordinal 0) will throw off your results on binary files. I think.

In any event `FTP_BINARY` should resolve your issue.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I think OP copied paste from php.net in this case. Docs use the `FTP_ASCII` in example. OP may have not realized the implications at the time and as the OP's project progressed, it simply was overlooked.